# Shopify with Gempages - show Image via metafield

Tags: shopify, liquid

We would like to have custom content on our product pages that is defined (referenced) from within custom product metafields (e.g. `product.metafields.custom.lifestyle_image_1`).  This is already possible using custom liquid code (including resize) as follows:

```
{% if product.metafields.custom.lifestyle_image_1 != blank %}
  {{ product.metafields.custom.lifestyle_image_1 | img_url: '512x768' | img_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

The downside is that the image **does not render** within gempages making it difficult to design your page.

Does anyone know how to get gempages to render images referenced in product metafields perhaps using the Image or Product element?